# Strange NullPointerException regarding constructors

Tags: java, swing, constructor, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a chat client/server. In the client, I have a class called `ClientGui`, and a subclass called `InputPane` which extends `JPanel`. `ClientGui` handles the major parts of the GUI related client things, but `InputPane` only handles the input from the user.

I keep getting a strange `NullPointerException` when trying to set the font in my `InputPane` object in the `ClientGui` class. Here is some of my code:

```
public ClientGui() {
    // configure JFrame

    this.serverOutput = new JTextPane();
    this.input = new InputPane();

    // configure JScrollPane

    // configure other objects

    // various set up methods

    frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(input, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}
```

As you can see, the `input` object is being initialized. Here is its constructor:

```
public InputPane() {
        this.inputField = new JTextField();
        this.send = new JButton("Send");

        // set size

        this.setFont(getFont());

        // various methods

        // add components
    }
```

When I try to set the font, it throws a `NullPointerException`. Through various `println()` calls, I was able to find out that `inputField` and `send` are null. I tried putting `println()` methods in the constructor, but none were called (and/or printed).

I am very confused by this. If anyone could give an explanation, it would help a lot. Thank you.

**EDIT**: Here is the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.dean.tcp.client.gui.ClientGui$InputPane.setFont(ClientGui.java:518)
at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.dean.tcp.client.gui.ClientGui$InputPane.<init>(ClientGui.java:496)
at net.dean.tcp.client.gui.ClientGui.<init>(ClientGui.java:138)
at net.dean.tcp.client.gui.ClientGui.main(ClientGui.java:44)
```

**EDIT 2**: Here is the `ClientGui$InputPane.setFont(Font)` method:

```
public void setFont(Font f) {
        super.setFont(f);
        inputField.setFont(f);
        send.setFont(f);

        Dimension size = getSizeFromFont(); 
        // Dimension based on getFont()'s height

        send.setPreferredSize(size);
        inputField.setPreferredSize(size);
    }
```

Comment: The UI may not be installed or initialised yet.  The stranger question is, why are you setting the font back to the same component?

Comment: Can you throw in the stacktrace?

Comment: Complete code would help here as well. Why is this tagged "nested-class"? I don't see any nesting.

Comment: @TedHopp This is tagged as nested class because InputPane is nested inside of ClientGui.

Comment: ClientGui.java:518, that's where the exception is occuring. Can you post the `ClientGui$InputPane.setFont` method?

Comment: @BheshGurung This is where I was getting at. The line it throws the `NullPointerException` is where it is setting `inputField`'s font. The font variable is not null, but `inputField` is.

Comment: @TedHopp Here is the [complete code](http://codetidy.com/3770/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Swing framework calls `setFont` as part of the `JPanel` constructor. Since this executes before the body of the constructor, `InputPane.setFont` is being called before the `send` and `inputField` member variables are initialized. The only clean solution here, I think, is to do an explicit null check inside `InputPane.setFont`:

```
public void setFont(Font f) {
    super.setFont(f);
    if (inputField != null) {
        inputField.setFont(f);
    }
    if (send != null) {
        send.setFont(f);
    }

    Dimension size = getSizeFromFont(); 
    // Dimension based on getFont()'s height

    if (send != null) {
        send.setPreferredSize(size);
    }
    if (inputField != null) {
        inputField.setPreferredSize(size);
    }
}
```

(You can probably reorganize your calls to reduce the number of null checks.)

As an aside, this is a good example of why [it is bad practice to call an overridable method from a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors). But Swing is what it is, and there's no profit in whining about it, so I'll stop here. :)

Comment: Why didn't I think of that? facepalms* Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting the font using `setFont` and you are getting it from `getFont` method and setting it. It is more likely that this `getFont()` returns NULL and that may be the reason. Also in my opinion neither `inputField` nor the `send` object can be NULL in `inputPane` object unless you make them NULL explicitly.

Comment: As I said in the question comments, "The line it throws the NullPointerException is where it is setting inputField's font. The font variable is not null, but inputField is."

Comment: @whowantsakookie not sure from exceptions details, for better help sooner post an SSCCE, because you mixing properties with fields that aren't initialized or they are ???,

Comment: @mKorbel I was trying to go for an SSCCE.